# Tkinter - Python3 Does Not Show The Image When Clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

I've tried several methods but did not worked. Suppose I am working on a project that changes the picture when the button is clicked.

Well as I know, all it did is I just clicked 1 time and the image turned white and I can not click it anymore. Quick! I need to complete this project in 1 hour deadline. Here is the code.

```py
# Modules
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Functions
def change_img():
    global curr_img
    global root
    global image1
    image1 = Image.open(f"Hamster {curr_img + 1}.jpg")
    image1 = image1.resize((100, 60))
    img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
    btn.configure(image=img1, command=change_img)
    root.update()
    curr_img += 1

# Main Window
root = Tk()
root.title("Picture Change")
root.geometry("300x150")
root.config(bg="black")

# Adding Objects
curr_img = 1
Label(root, text="My Favorite Animal", fg="white", bg="black", font=("Arial bold", "20")).pack() # This is a label.
image1 = Image.open("Hamster 1.jpg") # First we open the image and save it into a variable.
image1 = image1.resize((100,60)) # Resizes the image.
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1) # Create a ImageTK object from the image1 variable.
btn = Button(image = img1, command=change_img) # Create a label and put the image into it.
btn.pack() # Pack the label that contains the image. Now, we repeat the process.

# Mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

> Thanks if the answer is quick and accurate. Comment, thanks very much too.

Comment: Any errors? Or any more details you can provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the next image in the `change_img()` function and when the function exits the reference to the image is garbage collected. You can save a reference to the image in the button widget:

```
btn.configure(image=img1, command=change_img)
btn.image = img1    # Save a reference to the new image
```